# How do I use the anchor tag for the logout in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am new to the `react-redux` , Here I have a logout functionality.

so, here

```
<div className="logout">
     <a href="#" onClick={this.logout()}>Logout</a>
 </div>
```

Now, In this I also want to clear the state of reducer. and want to redirect user to the login page.

Now,

what I did was

```
logout = () => {


    this.props.logout()

}




  export default logout = () => {

     localstorage.clear();
    history.push('/login');

    }
```

So, Here , can any one suggest me the way to work with anchors.

Comment: Are you using react router?

Comment: yes I am using  react router

Comment: From a styling point of view, I think the suggested way is to use a `<button>` instead of an anchor and then style the button as a link so you wouldn't need to add an href and then prevent the default click action.

Answer (score 2):

// Remove parentheses or the method will be called at every render

```
<div className="logout">
  <a href="#" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a>
</div>
```

Stop the propagation and default anchor behavior:

```
logout = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout()
}
```

Comment: what about the href=""#

Comment: For most of the linters href must be present. _e.preventDefault()_ will prevent  _#_ to be added to the url